# tidyselect changes how to refer an external vector of variable names in selecting functions in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyselect

I have started to recieve a warning when using selecting functions within `tidyverse` packages.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(
  "id" = c(rep("G1", 3), rep("G2", 4), rep("G3", 3)),
  "total" = sample.int(n = 10),
  "C1" = sample.int(n=10),
  "C2" = sample.int(n=10),
  "C3" = sample.int(n=10))
cols.to.sum = c("C1", "C2")
df.selected = df %>% 
  dplyr::select(total, cols.to.sum)
```

Giving:

```
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(cols.to.sum)` instead of `cols.to.sum` to silence this message.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.
```

It does not warning if I refactor to:

```
df.selected = df %>% 
  dplyr::select(total, all_of(cols.to.sum))
```

This behaviour has changed from `tidyselect_0.2.5` to `tidyselect_1.0.0`. There was no warning untill now.

On documentation about this change (https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html) it is stated that this is just a warning but it will turn into an error in the future.

My question here is how to deal such a change regarding the existing code.

Should I refactor every single line of code that uses this selection method to add the `all_of()` to external vector reference? That sounds something hard to accomplish when there might be hundreds of pieces in code where a selection has been made this way (it also affects to other functions such as 
`summarise_at` for example).

Would the only alternative be to stick to `tidyselect_0.2.5` to keep running code working?

What is the way to go on changes like this in a package regarding the existing code?

Thanks

Comment: This [github](https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/issues/76) thread might be a more appropriate venue for this question

Answer (score 1):

If *should* is the operative phrase in your first question then it might just be a matter of ensuring that none of your variables are named `cols.to.sum`. So long as this is the case, the attributes of using `all_of()` are not going to be relevant to your use case and you can keep `select`ing as usual.

If you don't want to stick to using an older version of `tidyselect` the [suppress library](https://rdrr.io/cran/pkgcond/man/suppress.html) might be helpful